# Migrate Documents from local drive into SharePoint with default metadata

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, document-migration, file-metadata

Want to migrate around 40 GB's of documents from windows File-Share to SP 2016 on-premise. 
Documents should be migrated to SP2016 with properties like;

1. Created date
2. Create by
3. Modified date
4. Modified by
5. Version

Could anyone please suggest any low cost migration tools ? 
(Microsoft SPMT tool supports only migration to cloud i.e. SharePoint Online)

Answer (score 4):

In this case you get what you pay for. I have done a fair number of migrations and none of the free offerings could provide the features we needed. 
Metalogixs and ShareGate are kind of the default tools and which one that might be the right choice for you is hard to say as it depends on the total amount of files ( how many test migrations) and additional features that might be of value for you.

https://www.metalogix.com/product/content-matrix

https://en.share-gate.com

Answer (score 2):

I have done fair amount of migrations cross different SharePoint versions. In this case, I will recommend ShareGate because (1) relatively low cost (2) able to keep document properties (3) they have 15-days trial and it's easier to install than Metalogix.

https://en.share-gate.com

Answer (score 1):

Try to user default functionality provided by SharePoint. "Open with Explorer" in IE.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend ShareGate. It was very easy and also user friendly and also and work perfectly.

It does require a license but it works on all kinds of sharepoint farms, collections & versions. Also the tech support that comes with the license is outstanding.

I think you can refer to below articles for more information about different people's views on "What’s the best SharePoint migration tool":

https://collab365.community/forum/topics/what-s-the-best-sharepoint-migration-tool/

https://collab365.community/sharepoint-comparison-matrix-for-3rd-party-migration-tools/